# Why is Qt telling me: expected class name?

Tags: c++, qt, header-files

Qt is complaining about deposit.h on line 5, saying "expected class name".

I know it's got something to do with my header files and the order in how I include them.
 But from I can see, everything should be okay? Deposit.h knows about Transaction.h, and vice versa.

Keep in mind, this is a work in progress. Shout if you need an implementation file.

**Deposit.h**

```
#ifndef DEPOSIT
#define DEPOSIT
#include "transaction.h"

class Deposit : public Transaction {
public:
   Deposit(double amount);
   QString toString() const;
   double computeCost() const;
private:
   double m_Amount;
   static double m_Fee;
};

#endif // DEPOSIT
```

**Transaction.h**

```
#ifndef TRANSACTION
#define TRANSACTION
#include <QString>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QList>
#include <QDate>
#include "deposit.h"

class Transaction  {
public:
   Transaction(QString type, QDateTime datetime);
   QString getType() const;
   QString toString() const;
   QDateTime getDateTime() const;
   virtual double computeCost() const = 0;
protected:
   QString m_Type;
   QDateTime m_DateTime;
};

#endif // TRANSACTION
```

**SavingsAccount.h**

```
#ifndef SAVINGSACCOUNT
#define SAVINGSACCOUNT
#include "transaction.h"

class SavingsAccount {
public:
    SavingsAccount(QString name, QString num);
    virtual ~SavingsAccount();
    void addTransaction(Transaction* t);
    double totalTransactionCost() const;
    QString frequentTransactionType() const;
    QList<Transaction*> transactionOnAdate(QDate date) const;
    virtual QString toString() const;
private:
    QString m_CustomerName;
    QString m_AccountNumber;
    QList<Transaction*> m_TransactionList;
};

#endif // SAVINGSACCOUNT
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "savingsaccount.h"

int main()
{
    QTextStream cout(stdout);
    QTextStream cin(stdin);
    SavingsAccount Acc("John Doe", "999");
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: will adding line `class Transaction;` before Deposit class definition help?

Comment: You have a circular dependency, `Transaction.h` depends on `Deposit.h` which depends on `Transaction.h`which depends on `Deposit.h` etc. It's easy to break this dependency in your case, since `Transaction.h` doesn't really need `Deposit.h` or anything in it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg isn't this why the #ifndef are used? that should just not interprete the recursion.

Comment: @SebastianLange, as far as I understand it, no. The header guard (#ifndef..) is there to prevent multiple includes of the same file. So, if A.h is included by both B.h and C.h, then it only pulls in A.h once. Two classes including each other can cause circular dependancy if forward declarations aren't included. If this is not right, I'd be happy to be corrected.

Comment: Removing `#include "deposit.h"` from Transaction.h works fine and compiles. But how will I go about creating a Deposit class within main.cpp when I require it?

Comment: @MichaelHanslo, I've added that to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where possible, use [forward declarations](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/17-forward-declarations/) in headers, rather than #including a header. For example, in the SavingsAccount class, you use Transaction pointers and not a Transaction instance, so including the Transaction header is not needed.

Besides being an overhead in compilation speed with the compiler having to open the included file and check the header guard, you can come up with problems such as those you are seeing due to circular dependancies.

So, change the SavingsAccount class to: -

```
#ifndef SAVINGSACCOUNT
#define SAVINGSACCOUNT

class Transaction; // forward declaration of the class Transaction

class SavingsAccount {

...

};
```

The Transaction class doesn't reference deposit, so the #include "deposit.h" can be removed.

If you then need to create a deposit class in main.cpp, add the #include "deposit.h" at the top of main.cpp